# Higher brightness LED with bigger resistor to save battery life

Tags: led, resistors, battery-operated

I need to run three LEDs for indoor indication purposes and want them to be around 500 - 1000 MCD. I will run them off batteries and I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to increase battery Life since I don't want them to be that Bright anyway.

They will be wired in parallel and need to be constantly lit when powered on. Series Circuit is not an option because I can't fit a higher voltage battery. 3-4AAA is the most I can fit inside. I also want to keep the Circuit as simple as possible.

I have some options for leds that are rated at Everything from 1000 - 15000 MCD. They are all rated at around 2-3.6V and 20mA.

Is it better to choose a brighter LED and run them at maybe 1-5mA or so to get the wanted brightness by adding bigger resistors or should I use a more appropriate LED for the wanted brightness with smaller resistors? They are all rated at 20mA.

I know that resistors waste energy but I'm not concerned with that as long as the energy wasted by the resistors is smaller than the energy saved by running the LEDs at lower currents. Unless it will get really hot because it's inside a box.

Comment: Oh and the Circuit will be powered by 4,5V.

Comment: You want to increase battery life but you're not bothered about resistors wasting energy? Make your mind up.

Comment: Is it really needed put keep them constantly lit? Why not a flash every second, or every so many milliseconds, so it has the feeling as if it lits continuously? Or flash the LEDs when a small button is pressed.

Comment: Yes but if the wasted energy in the resistor is less than the energy saved by running a higher brightness LED at lower current I should increase battery Life. Or is the wasted energy by resistors bigger?

Comment: Be careful as the highest rated LED's often also have the smallest angle. Thus you get more of a spot-light.

Comment: Blinking is not an option in this case.

Comment: oldfart: The led holders have diffused lenses on them so that is not a problem. In fact, it's better than the light being wasted lighting up the inside of the box.

Comment: Provide links to data sheets for two LEDs you are considering then maybe someone can do a simple calculation for you. At the moment your question cannot be resolved without data sheet examples.

Comment: I will look for other leds wih datasheets. The site I'm ordering from does not have datasheets for their leds.

Comment: @enessabanovic then you definitely ordered from the wrong site. Also, you've got serious misunderstandings. "The energy wasted in the resistor is less than the energy […] saved" is plain wrong. Energy = time · power. Power = current · voltage. Voltage is fixed (your supply voltage), current defined by your LED's forward current.

Comment: Marcus Muller: It's possible I may have misunderstood how it works. Voltage is fixed yes but from what I understand I can run LED's at lower currents and get less brightness which is what I want to do. If I can run them at 5mA it should consume less than if I run them at 20mA. Or have I misunderstood how this works?

Comment: Here is a datasheet of two possible high brightness LEDs:https://www.electron.com/leds-c371/?af=NTMoVGhyb3VnaC1Ib2xlKik0NCgzbW0qNC44bW0qNW1tKik0NShaZWxlbsOhKik0OCg0MDAwfjgwMDBtY2QqNjAwMH4xMjAwMG1jZCo4MDAwfjE2MDAwbWNkKjEwMDAwfjE1MDAwbWNkKjEwMDAwfjIyMDAwbWNkKjEyMDAwfjI0MDAwbWNkKik=

Comment: Here is one with less brightness: https://www.electron.com/leds-c371/?af=NTMoVGhyb3VnaC1Ib2xlKik0NShaZWxlbsOhKik0OCgxNTAwfjMwMDBtY2QqKQ==

Comment: ah, ok, yes, in that case: indeed, simply don't use the LED that has 1/11 of the Lumen / Watt as the other. You're clearly right about that. However, as you've been told by @oldfart, the opening angles of these two are different! So, you're illuminating less space! That would explain the difference in intensity! It's not that one is 11 times as efficient electrically as the other, it's that it focuses the same light of 1/11 of the opening angle.

Comment: Also, I'm always fascinated where people find distributors for small Chinese "backalley" fabs without proper english data sheets :) Try mouser.com, digikey.com, arrow.com, element14.com, rs-components.com . These are large distributors that will deliver components in very few days, all around the globe, and don't seem to be much more expensive than the shop you dug up!

Answer (score 4):

Other things being equal, so the same battery voltage, running high brightness LEDs at 5mA will use less power than running standard LEDs at 20mA.

In each case, if you are controlling the LED current with resistors, then you would use larger resistors for the lower current.

In each case, your efficiency would be the LED voltage divided by the battery voltage.

If you have a much higher battery voltage than your LED voltage, then you could improve efficiency by using a constant current output SMPS, instead of a resistor. However, resistors are cheaper and simpler.